# ¿Asignacion de varios datos a una sola primary key?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas a todos mi pregunta es la siguiente,¿Puedo darle varias asignaciones a una primary key?, en este momento estoy haciendo una base de datos para un ejercicio de mi universidad y queria darle varias asignaciones a una sola primary key pero a la hora de hacer los inserts no me deja hacerlos dejare mi codigo.

```
 **create table Integrantes(
   nombre varchar (50),
   id_integrante int,
   contraseña varchar (100),
   cc int,
   telefono int,
   correo varchar (100),
   carrera varchar (100),
   id_dependencia int,
   id_formacion int,
   PRIMARY KEY (id_integrante),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Dependencia_Integrantes 
   FOREIGN KEY (id_dependencia) REFERENCES Dependencia(id_dependencia),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Grupo_formacion_Integrantes 
   FOREIGN KEY (id_formacion) REFERENCES Grupo_formacion(id_formacion)
   );


   create table Grupo_investigacion(
   id_grupoinvestigacion int,
   id_integrante int,
   PRIMARY KEY (id_grupoinvestigacion),
   CONSTRAINT fk_Integrantes_Grupo_investigacion 
   FOREIGN KEY (id_integrante) REFERENCES Integrantes(id_Integrante)
   );

   insert into `Grupo_investigacion` value(1,10);
   insert into `Grupo_investigacion` value(1,11);**
```

y no me deja hacer la asignacion porque estoy repitiendo la primary key saben que puedo hacer?

Comment: Una primary key siempre, siempre, siempre es una clave única y no se puede repetir bajo ningún concepto: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191236(v=sql.105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si requieres una tabla donde una llave primaria se pueda registrar múltiples veces, se puede pero a través de una relación de muchos a muchos lo cual va a depender enteramente de la lógica de negocios que estes resolviendo; te pongo un ejemplo de como es que quedaría:

```
CREATE TABLE integrantes_grupo_investigacion(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   integrante_id INT NOT NULL,
   grupo_investigacion_id INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT integrantes_grupo_investigacion_integrantes FOREIGN KEY(integrante_id) REFERENCES integrantes(id),
   CONSTRAINT integrantes_grupo_investigacion_Grupo_investigacion FOREIGN KEY(grupo_investigacion_id) REFERENCES Grupo_investigacion(id)
);
```

> De la manera anterior, esta tabla de muchos a muchos te va a permitir
>   por cada registro, múltiples llaves primarias de las otras dos tablas,
>   ya que para esta tabla son llaves foráneas que no deben cumplir la
>   regla de ser registros únicos; una vez mas te aclaro esta solución
>   funciona si tu lógica de negocios demanda que tengas una tabla del
>   tipo muchos a muchos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, la logica que estoy manejando es que a un grupo pertenecen muchos integrantes, creo que esta solucion me podra ser de ayuda, voy a implementarla y reviso que tal va.

Answer (score 3):

Si necesitas insertar dos veces la misma llave, entonces no debes utilizar esa llave; en tu ejemplo parece que necesitas una **llave compuesta**:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id_grupoinvestigacion, id_integrante)
```

De esta forma podrás repetir `id_grupoinvestigacion` y `id_integrante` pero no la combinación de ambos campos.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder,voy a implementarlo y vere como funciona.

Comment: En otro post me encontré con este tema que me es desconocido, yo quisiera saber que ventajas tiene y cómo y cuando utilizarlas? Me casé con el concepto que por tabla es una `primary key` y ahora conozco que se puede hacer una `primary key compuesta`